# 'Convert' a many object in single array to have 'One Array One Object'

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to create a 'One Array One Object' if i have an array variable like this

```
const honey = [
  {
    name: "Caroline",
    location: "Colorado",
  },
  {
    name: "Sarashina",
    location: "Tokyo",
  },
];
```

to like this?

```
[{
    name : 'Caroline',
    location : 'Colorado',
    }],
    [{
    name : 'Sarashina',
    location : 'Tokyo',
}];
```

Comment: Looks like a nice opportunity for a `.map` , give it a try and come back if you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.map` function to achieve this functionality.

```js
const honey = [{
    name : 'Caroline',
    location : 'Colorado',
},
{
    name : 'Sarashina',
    location : 'Tokyo',
}];

// Here item is each element object of the above array.
// By doing item => [item], we are taking the item 
// and return an array  of length 1 containing that object
const newarray = honey.map(item => [item]);

console.log(newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not a valid structure - I imagine you either want an array that contains other arrays (each with 1 element), or you want to break out each item in the original array into it's own single-element array variable.

For the latter, you could use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then destructure each into its own variable, for example:

```js
const honey = [{
    name: 'Caroline',
    location: 'Colorado',
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarashina',
    location: 'Tokyo',
  }
];

// Create a new array of arrays then destructure each sub-array into its own variable
const [caroline, sarashina] = honey.map(obj => [obj]);

console.log(caroline);
console.log(sarashina);
```

Comment: The code above might be effective if the array has very few objects, but what if the array is the result of MongoDB (db.collection.find({}).toArray), which has many objects in the array, and the number is uncertain?

Comment: I assume your saying that approach wouldnt make sense if your original array has many objects because there would be too many items to destructure, right? If that's the case then I agree. You could, however, use a simple for loop to extract items from the large array.